# Android Client Server Architecture for id not matching between them

Tags: java, android, android-studio, server, android-sqlite

First I will explain my problem statement clearly

I have a app for capturing information from the user and upload that data to server

For that I'm using `SyncAdapter` and `ContentProvider` in my android app.

Now I will discuss about database

> My database column structure is `[ID,data1,data2,...]`
>
> In server side also same structure is followed.

Usually I want to upload the Id and data from the android app.

**Problem Scenario is:**

Let say I have 15 data in the server. Next i want to continue form Id 16. For that I can able to get latest Id from the server.

But sometimes i didnt have Internet Connectivity , I that case also my app should not stuck ( Offline mode)

> **Problem 1**: In that case i didnt have latest Id so i started from again
>   1 or last id I have in local database.
>
> **Problem 2**: If my app crashed I lost the local database, In that case
>   how to handle that Id management? Means Sync should happen
>   independently on local database.

Both problem causing Id mismatching.

Is there any architecture pattern to avoid this problem?.

If you have any further any doubts regarding to problem statement please let me know

Comment: why do you need those rowIDs to be the same?

Comment: Website is going to be run depend upon the data in the server. For that Id is important. Id is also going to display in the website.